# is it possible to Postback only Specific tools?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my aspx page there are entry form with 10 text boxes,
1 drop-down(auto postback = true) 
and two buttons.

dropdown SelectedIndexChanged fills two text box value.

button1 name:  "add" &  button2 name:"update"
On page load "update" `visible = false`

when click on "edit" from gridview,  "add" `visible = false` and 
"update" visible = true. 
because of default page load "update" `visible = false` when i change drop-down,
"update" button  invisible.

So is it possible to Postback only Specific tools(in my case textbox) ?

Currently i am try with below code behind dropdown (i know it's crazy)

`if (addbtn.Visible == true) {Button2.Visible = false;}`

`else if (addbtn.Visible == false) { Button2.Visible = true;}`

---

### page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox15.Enabled = false;
        TextBox16.Enabled = false;
        Button2.Visible = false;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bind_dropdown();

        }

   }
```

---

### GridView rowcommand

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "editform")
        {
          addbtn.Visible = false;
          Button2.Visible = true;
        }
```

---

### bind dropdown

```
private void bind_dropdown()
    {
       DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CITYNAME";
       DropDownList1.DataValueField = "AID";
       DropDownList1.DataBind();
      }
```

---

### dropdown change event

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (addbtn.Visible == true)
        {
            Button2.Visible = false;

        }
        else if (addbtn.Visible == false)
        {

            Button2.Visible = true;
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            TextBox15.Text = "";
            TextBox16.Text = "";



        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
```

Comment: `Button2.Visible = !addbtn.Visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax, or update panel will do the trick, if you want to solve this with pure code behind, passing correct parameter to determine the layout can be done with validate the parameters and toggle the visible attribute in the page load.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't give your code I can only guess what you're trying to achieve.

The best way to deal with this kind of problem is probably using AJAX as MKH proposed.

If you don't want to deal with AJAX you can also do it this way :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn" OnClick="btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Default", "-1"));
            ddown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text 0", "0"));
            ddown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text 1", "1"));
            ddown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text 2", "2"));
        }
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ddown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text = ddown.SelectedItem.Text;
        btn.Visible = false;
    }
```

This way, you put in the "If(!Page.IsPostBack)" only the code that must be init once.

Then with the you can manage the "Visible" part from SelectedIndexChanged.

THis answer is not complete as I didn't totally understand what you need but that can be a piece of answer if AJAX scares you ;)

Comment: thanks.  i am already managing  using   btn.Visible = false; and  btn.Visible = true;

Comment: I don't think the problem is on your Visible/Hide management but more on where you use them and how you deal with Postback. Could you share your code so we can help ?

Comment: If I understand well, your problem is that the page load put the button update back to invisible ? In this case why don't you put the "visible = false" in the If(!Page.IsPostBack) ?

Comment: And actually I would suggest to put also the textbox disable in the condition too.